# Call to parent method of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I am pretty new with c++ and I'm trying to call a parent virtual method from his child, which actually is a templated class. And i get the following error:

```
dependent-name 'bList<T>::bNode' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
```

I have reviewed other post and tried different combinations, but not managed to solve it.

```
template <class T>
class bList {
    protected:
        class bNode
        {
            // PARENT METHOD:
            public:
                virtual void chain() {
                    // do something...
                }
        };

    protected:
        virtual bNode* makeNode(T& data) {
            return new bNode();
        }   
};

template <class T>
class cList : public bList<T> {
    protected:
        class cNode : public virtual bList<T>::bNode {

            // CHILD METHOD:
            public:
                virtual typename bList<T>::bNode* chain(typename bList<T>::bNode* node) {
//                  if (...) {
//                      return ...
//                  } 
//                  else {
                        return bList<T>::bNode.chain(node); // <- error!
//                  }
                }
        };

    protected:
        virtual typename bList<T>::bNode* makeNode(T& data) {
            return new cNode();
        }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean `bList<T>::bNode::chain(node)`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while was trying to simplify code in order to post it. Originally the signature was ok. Using `this->bList<T>::bNode::chain(node);` Solved the problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class bList {
    protected:
        class bNode
        {
            // PARENT METHOD:
            public:
            virtual typename bList<T>::bNode* node chain(typename bList<T>::bNode* node) {
                // do something...
            }
        };

    protected:
        virtual bNode* makeNode(T& data) {
            return new bNode();
        }
};

template <class T>
class cList : public bList<T> {
    protected:
        class cNode : public virtual bList<T>::bNode {

            // CHILD METHOD:
            public:
                virtual typename bList<T>::bNode* chain(typename bList<T>::bNode* node) {
//                  if (...) {
//                      return ...
//                  }
//                  else {

                        return this->bList<T>::bNode::chain(node);
//                      }
                }
        };

    protected:
        virtual typename bList<T>::bNode* makeNode(T& data) {
            return new cNode();
        }
};
```

I have corrected your question and give a proper answer. The problem with your question was you werent overriding the function properly. Your chain functions have different signatures.